# Reading Bigtable Counters in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-bigtable

I have a counters table in Bigtable. what is the right way to read the counters data in BigQuery?

When I read the row using BigQuery, all the cell values shows up as 0 when cast to Integer.

```
SELECT integer (daily.column.cell.value) FROM rtda.counters
```

Here is the example output using hbase shell:

```
hbase(main):019:0> get_counter 'counters','20110101','daily:clicks'
```

COUNTER VALUE = 8

I set column family encoding to be of type bytes. `bq show rtda.counters` output :

```
   Last modified                 Schema                  Type     Total 
 URIs   Expiration   Labels  
 ----------------- ---------------------------------- ---------- ------------ ------------ -------- 
 10 May 11:10:38   |- rowkey: string                  EXTERNAL   1                                 
                   +- daily: record                                                                
                   |  +- column: record (repeated)                                                 
                   |  |  |- name: string                                                           
                   |  |  +- cell: record (repeated)                                                
                   |  |  |  |- timestamp: timestamp                                                
                   |  |  |  |- value: bytes                                                        
                   +- weekly: record                                                               
                   |  +- column: record (repeated)                                                 
                   |  |  |- name: string                                                           
                   |  |  +- cell: record (repeated)                                                
                   |  |  |  |- timestamp: timestamp                                                
                   |  |  |  |- value: bytes                                                        
                   +- monthly: record                                                              
                   |  +- column: record (repeated)                                                 
                   |  |  |- name: string                                                           
                   |  |  +- cell: record (repeated)                                                
                   |  |  |  |- timestamp: timestamp                                                
                   |  |  |  |- value: bytes
```

Comment: Can you please add details for how you configured the BigQuery-Bigtable federation, in particular, what encoding did you set for that column?